# std::vector sort is not working

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

i tried to sort a vector contains structure. i have to sort based on a member in the structure . sorting i used std::sort function and argument as the structure reference and member to check condition.

```
QStringList keys =  m_pLDFFrameMap.keys();

    foreach (QString key, keys) {
        LDFFrameData frmData = m_pLDFFrameMap.value(key);
        vector<LDFSignalsData> myList;
        QList <LDFSignalsData>sigData = frmData.m_SignalDataList;
        for (int i =0; i < sigData.size(); i++) {

            LDFSignalsData signal = sigData.at(i);
            qDebug()<<"Before signal:"<<signal.startBits<<"Name:"<<signal.frameSignals;
            myList.push_back(signal);
        }

        foreach (LDFSignalsData sig1, myList) {
            qDebug()<<"Signal act data:"<<sig1.startBits<<"Name:"<<sig1.frameSignals;

        }
        sort(myList.begin(), myList.end(), sortingSignals);
        for(int i =0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            qDebug()<<"After sorting signal:"<<myList.at(i).startBits<<"Name:"<<myList.at(i).frameSignals;
        }
    }
```

and the sort function sortingSignals() is

```
bool sortingSignals(const LDFSignalsData &first, const LDFSignalsData &second)
 {

    if (first.startBits < second.startBits)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
 }
```

but the output is not coming as desired. this is my log message

> Signal act data: " **0** " Name: "    LIN_Comm_Status"
>
> Signal act data: " ***1*** " Name: "    Motor_Relay_Fault"
>
> Signal act data: " **2** " Name: "    Hall_Fault"
>
> Signal act data: " **3** " Name: "    Thermal_Protection_Active"
>
> Signal act data: " **4** " Name: "    Motor_Reversing"
>
> Signal act data: " **5** " Name: "    Uncalibration_Mode"
>
> Signal act data: " **6** " Name: "    SS_LINBus_com_state"
>
> Signal act data: " **8** " Name: "    Switch_Input_Status"
>
> Signal act data: " **16** " Name: "    PosnSts1_Glass"
>
> Signal act data: " **32** " Name: "    App_Version_DayNo"
>
> Signal act data: " **40** " Name: "    App_Version_WeekNo"
>
> Signal act data: " **48** " Name: "    App_Version_Year"
>
> Signal act data: " **24** " Name: "    PosnSts2_Blind"
>
> Signal act data: " **11** " Name: "    TSts_Glass"
>
> Signal act data: " **12** " Name: "    TSts_Blind1"

and after sorting

> After sorting signal: " **0** " Name: "    LIN_Comm_Status"
>
> After sorting signal: " **1** " Name: "    Motor_Relay_Fault"
>
> After sorting signal: " **11** " Name: "    TSts_Glass"
>
> After sorting signal: " **12** " Name: "    TSts_Blind1"
>
> After sorting signal: " **16** " Name: "    PosnSts1_Glass"
>
> After sorting signal: " **2** " Name: "    Hall_Fault"
>
> After sorting signal: " **24** " Name: "    PosnSts2_Blind"
>
> After sorting signal: " **3** " Name: "    Thermal_Protection_Active"
>
> After sorting signal: " **32** " Name: "    App_Version_DayNo"
>
> After sorting signal: " **4** " Name: "    Motor_Reversing"
>
> After sorting signal: " **40** " Name: "    App_Version_WeekNo"
>
> After sorting signal: " **48** " Name: "    App_Version_Year"
>
> After sorting signal: " **5** " Name: "    Uncalibration_Mode"
>
> After sorting signal: " **6** " Name: "    SS_LINBus_com_state"
>
> After sorting signal: " **8** " Name: "    Switch_Input_Status"

i have to sort the structure in the list based on the member start bit but even the proper ascending vector is not sorted properly.

Comment: What's the type of `startBits`?

Comment: what is this 'foreach' ? I think there is something more than c++,sorting,vector,stl.. please tag the correct ones

Comment: @mash : thanks for reply. startBit is an integer .

Comment: @HumamHelfawi that's Qt

Comment: @humam : thanks for reply. this is more like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: @Wagmare are you sure that `startBits` is an integer? -.-

Comment: @Wagmare yes I know but this is not exactly std::for_each. I think tagging you question with Qt or the right framework would be better

Comment: @Wagmare -- Downvoting.  Instead of describing what certain important variables are, you should post the exact declaration of `startBits`.  You started a whole thread going in the wrong direction trying to solve your problem due to not posting the proper information.

Answer (score 8):

Your sort result is in charactor sequence, e.g. "2" < "24" < "3".

I believe your "startBits" is something like `std::string`, and your `sortingSignals()` is comparing `string` instead of the values.

So your sort is working, but in another way.

To really get your desired result, you may convert the `string` to `int` and compare the `int` values in `sortingSignals()`

Comment: but the OP stated that `startBits` is an integer.

Comment: The elements are sorted in lexicographical order, just so you know :)

Comment: Well... when I write the answer I did not see the comments says it's integer. But from the result, I still think `startBits` is not integer, otherwise the output does not make sense.

Comment: yes you are right i made a mistake of declaring qstring instead of int .